# Object required error from If syntax?

Tags: object, if-statement, required

The below syntax:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
If Hour(Now) < 7 Then MonthView1.Value = Date - 1
If Hour(Now) >= 7 Then MonthView1.Value = Date
WorksOrder.SetFocus
End Sub
```

generates the error: Object required
Highlighting the "MonthView1.Value = Date" from the 3rd line

Can anyone see the issue please?
Using Excel 2007